# filte grayscale is not working in internet explorer

Tags: html, css

can anybody else help me solve grayscale filter is not working on internet explorer any solution ? any other solution ? Thanks

```css
.blog-image img {
  transition: 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: 0.3s ease-in-out; 
}
.blog-image img:hover {
  filter: grayscale(100%);
  -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);
  -moz-filter: grayscale(100%);
  -ms-filter: grayscale(100%);
}
```

```html
<div class="blog-image">
  <img src="http://placekitten.com/1000/500" />
</div>
```

Comment: IE10 does not support DX filters as IE9 and earlier have done, nor does it support a prefixed version of the greyscale filter.
However, you can use an SVG overlay in IE10 to accomplish the greyscaling.

Comment: Have you any example ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use a grayscale overlay like this...

```
img.grayscale:hover {
    filter: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns=\'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg\'><filter id=\'grayscale\'><feColorMatrix type=\'matrix\' values=\'1 0 0 0 0, 0 1 0 0 0, 0 0 1 0 0, 0 0 0 1 0\'/></filter></svg>#grayscale");
}

svg {
    background:url(http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-IzPWLqY4gJ0/T01CPzNb1KI/AAAAAAAACgA/_8uyj68QhFE/s400/a2cf7051-5952-4b39-aca3-4481976cb242.jpg);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use filter:url for IEas shown below:

```
 filter: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns=\'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg\'><filter id=\'grayscale\'><feColorMatrix type=\'matrix\' values=\'1 0 0 0 0, 0 1 0 0 0, 0 0 1 0 0, 0 0 0 1 0\'/></filter></svg>#grayscale");
```

or

```
filter: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,&lt;svg xmlns=\'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg\'&gt;&lt;filter id=\'grayscale\'&gt;&lt;feColorMatrix type=\'matrix\' values=\'1 0 0 0 0, 0 1 0 0 0, 0 0 1 0 0, 0 0 0 1 0\'/&gt;&lt;/filter&gt;&lt;/svg&gt;#grayscale");
```

also check cross browser support: [cross-browser-grayscale-ie](https://www.majas-lapu-izstrade.lv/cross-browser-grayscale-ie11/)

Answer (score 0):

IE doesn't support filter:

[Can I Use](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-filters)

But you can use This:

```
img.grayscale:hover {
    filter: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns=\'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg\'><filter id=\'grayscale\'><feColorMatrix type=\'matrix\' values=\'1 0 0 0 0, 0 1 0 0 0, 0 0 1 0 0, 0 0 0 1 0\'/></filter></svg>#grayscale");
}

svg {
    background:url(http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-IzPWLqY4gJ0/T01CPzNb1KI/AAAAAAAACgA/_8uyj68QhFE/s400/a2cf7051-5952-4b39-aca3-4481976cb242.jpg);
}
```